# How do I make an isometric hitbox?

Tags: java

I am making a game in Java that uses an isometric grid pseudo-3D system. It uses tiles that have this basic shape:

[image: Isometric tile]

I can't work out how to make a hitbox that covers all the area of a tile, and only the area of a tile. I need this because all my tiles are stacked and hitbox stacking can produce unwanted results.

Comment: It would depend a bit on your targeted framework (as it might already support the functionality), but at a very basic level, you could make use of the Java2D's `Shape` API to create a polygon representing the shape of the tile and use it's `contains` and `intersects` functionality

Comment: Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend a bit on your targeted framework (as it might already support the functionality), but at a very basic level, you could make use of the Java2D's Shape API to create a polygon representing the shape of the tile and use it's contains and intersects functionality

[As a conceptual example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423506/how-do-you-make-text-in-a-frame-change-dependent-on-cursor-position/28423538#28423538)